# How to make gradle jar append to manifest instead of overwrite?

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to have a gradle 'jar' task append to an existing manifest file in the project, instead of creating one on the fly. Is that possible? The idea behind is to have the static manifest entries (vendor, name, etc) in a file, and the dynamic entries (version, build number, etc) added in the build.gradle. I can have them all in the build.gradle, but if want to use/expose them in an application feature they are only available when executing the JAR, not when running the application via the IDE or `gradle run`.

The [Manifest documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html) doesn't seem to expose that feature.

Answer (score 0):

A gradle script is essentially groovy so you could read in the file containing the static entries and then write those into the manifest using either the attributes method or from method on the Manifest. Reading the file should be a separate task and the manifest can take the output of that task.

If the static file is a property file I would recommend using ConfigSlurper

Answer (score 0):

guys. I think u can configure Gradle script like this:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-all'

    manifest = project.manifest {
        from jar.manifest // sthing u need to add.
    }
}
```

I hope its' help to u.